# ADO.NET asynchronous methods not throwing exceptions

Tags: c#, ado.net, async-await

I have a Web API 2 endpoint set up to test a 2+ second **ADO.NET** call.  When attempting to "burst" this api, it fails horribly when using async methods.  I'm getting connection timeouts and reader timeouts.  This doesn't happen with the synchronous version of this method when "bursted".  The real problem is as follows...

*Async* *ADO.NET* behaves strangely when exceptions are thrown.  I can see the exceptions thrown in the Visual Studio output, but they are not caught by my code.  As you'll see below, I've tried wrapping try/catches around just about everything and have had no results.  I did this to be able to set break points.  I understand that catching exceptions just to throw them is bad.  Initially, I only wrapped the call in the API layer.  The worst part is, this locks up the entire server.

Clearly, there's something I'm missing about async *ADO.NET*.  Any ideas?

EDIT:
Just to clarify what I'm trying to do here.  This is just some test code on my local computer that's talking to our developmental database.  It was just to prove/disprove that we can handle more traffic with async methods against our longer running db calls.  I think what's happening is that as the calls are stacking up.  In doing so, the await'ed connections and readers are timing out because we're not getting back to them quickly enough.  This is why it doesn't fail when it's ran synchronously.  This is a completely different issue.  My concern here is that the operations are not throwing exceptions in a way that can be caught.  The below is not production code :)

*Web API2 Controller:*

```
    [Route("api/async/books")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBookAsync()
    {
        // database class instantiation removed

        // search args instantiation removed

        try
        {
            var books = await titleData.GetTitlesAsync(searchArgs);

            return Ok(books);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

*Data Access:*

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Book>> GetTitlesAsync(SearchArgs args)
    {

        var procName = "myProc"

        using(var connection = new SqlConnection(_myConnectionString))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(procName, connection) { CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, CommandTimeout = 90 })
        {

           // populating command parameters removed

            var results = new List<Book>();

            try
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }

            try
            {
                using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            // FROM MSDN:
                            // http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/07/15/using-sqldatareader-s-new-async-methods-in-net-4-5-beta-part-2-examples.aspx
                            // Since this is non-sequential mode,
                            // all columns should already be read in by ReadAsync
                            // Therefore we can access individual columns synchronously

                            var book = new Book
                            {
                                Id = (int)reader["ID"],
                                Title = reader.ValueOrDefault<string>("Title"),
                                Author = reader.ValueOrDefault<string>("Author"),
                                IsActive = (bool)reader["Item_Active"],
                                ImageUrl = GetBookImageUrl(reader.ValueOrDefault<string>("BookImage")),
                                ProductId = (int)reader["ProductID"],
                                IsExpired = (bool)reader["Expired_Item"]
                            };

                            results.Add(book);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }

            return results;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where specifically does it seem to fail?  That is, what is throwing an exception in Visual Studio (and what *is* that exception) which isn't being caught by the `catch` statements.  Also, I realize you allude to it in your question, but be aware that `throw ex;` is harmful to debugging efforts.  Even if all you want to do is re-throw for testing purposes, use `throw;` instead.

Comment: It failed most of the time in command.ExecuteReaderAsync().  Message was "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.".  When I tried increased the command timeout, I starting getting the exceptions from the connection.OpenAsync().  That exception was: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  I'm able to see the exceptions in the Visual Studio output window and I can sometimes catch them if I turn on CLR exceptions.  Most of the time, no exceptions are actually throw in code

Comment: I'm less concerned about the databases problems, and more concerned that I can't catch the exceptions.  The responses never come back to the client and the server locks up.  It's dead locking.

Comment: Completely agree, I was mainly curious about the exception details for completeness of understanding the problem.  I must be missing the same thing you are, because I would expect that exception to be caught by its immediate parent try/catch block.  And then for each new exception you're throwing to be caught by its respective try/catch parent.

Comment: As a reminder, I understand my exception handling in the data access is not good.  I just put all that in there to try and catch the exceptions that were not being caught in my api layer.  Just needed a place to put a breakpoint.  Regardless of where the try/catches are, no exceptions are actually thrown in the code.  It's very odd.

Comment: Understood, I just wanted to point out the difference between `throw ex;` and `throw;`.  Both accomplish what you want, but the latter doesn't clobber the stack trace of the original exception like the former does.  (Just suggested since you might not know about the latter, a lot of people don't.)  The former should never be used, not even in this manual debugging scenario.  (If I had my way it would generate a compile error.)

Comment: Is the problem that Visual Studio is just showing you exceptions that are caught by EF?

Comment: By EF do you mean Entity Framework?  If so, no, I am not using Entity Framework.

Comment: The very first thing to check is that you're targeting .NET 4.5 **and** have `httpRuntime.targetFramework` set to `4.5` in your `web.config`.