# SqlDataReader and T-SQL: no exception propagated when using 'try...catch' with 'throw' while using an 'Async' call from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, asynchronous, ado.net

I get a datareader from a command like this:

```
reader = command.ExecuteReaderAsync()
```

MRE Command text:

```
begin try
    exec('select * from (SELECT 1 as ID) as nnn where ID = ''sdfsdf''') 
end try 
begin catch 
    throw;
end catch
```

This command results in an error from SQL:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'sdfsdf' to data type int

But if I use `reader.Read()` it returns no result with no error.
Making transaction rolled back without any information.

How can I get information about error that occurred during executing reader?

Comment: What is the type of column ID? If it's not varchar, text, string... you can't compare to a string. I'm not that advanced in SQL to understand `from (SELECT 1 as ID)` as is, but here are you comparing `if ( (int)1 == (string)"sdfsdf" )` ???

Comment: ID is integer. This comparision is invalid, but it gives no error when executed via reader

Comment: @.Kye I don't know T-SQL yet, nor interop with ADO.NET and exception propagation, sorry. Perhaps a setting, a flag or a proterty somewhere. Perhaps due to async: [ADO.NET asynchronous methods not throwing exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160814/ado-net-asynchronous-methods-not-throwing-exceptions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to progress to your TSQL CATCH block, execution of the `exec` completes and sends a zero-row resultset and a "rowcount" to the client before you `THROW` the caught exception.

You can see the changed order by turning on

```
con.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;
con.InfoMessage += (s, a) => Console.WriteLine($"Message: {a.Message}");
```

If you run

```
exec('select * from (SELECT 1 as ID) as nnn where ID = ''sdfsdf''')
```

you'll see the error message before the call to SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() returns.  But with the CATCH and THROW SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() returns before the error message is received.

You can trap the error like this:

```
using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    do
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            //. . .
        }
    }
    while (rdr.NextResult());  //this will throw the SqlException
}
```